# Visual Studio 2012 - Import/Export GitHub Gists

Tags: github, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets, gist

I came accross the following post: [Sexy Code Snippet Management With Gists](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sexy-code-snippet-management-with-gists/)
by Jeffrey Way describing how to **manage and share snippets using GitHub from within Sublime Text 2**.

He uses a plugin to easily import and export Gists from GitHub.

I want to do the same in VS2012, but don't find a plugin or solution to do this. There is [Gister](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b31916b0-c026-4c27-9d6b-ba831093f6b2) which allows one to create Gists but it does not do any importing.

Does anyone know of another plugin or similar solution to do this?

Comment: did you find anything good?

Comment: I have not found anything yet. Still looking...

Comment: Looks like gister doing one way http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b31916b0-c026-4c27-9d6b-ba831093f6b2

Answer (score 1):

For importing gists into Visual Studio, keep in mind that every gist is a normal git repository. As a result, you should be able to use a plugin like 
[Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) to clone the Git repo of a gist.

As you mentioned in your question, you should be able to use [Gister](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b31916b0-c026-4c27-9d6b-ba831093f6b2) for other gist-related features.